# How to make a Input field in AEM/CRX required?

Tags: input, aem, required, crx

since our AEM guy is out of office at the moment, i need to fix something in our CRX. I have a form with a checkbox in my website, where authors can set a text next to it. Now i am trying to add the functionality to set this checkbox to be required from the authoring dialog.

I was able to find a textfield which has this property in authoring, but in the html in CRX i only see the code `required=${required}`, where other fields like label are shown like `${properties.label}` and have a corresponding node in CRX. I don't understand how the required is implemented and need help here.

I already tried to add `required=${required}` to my checkbox input markup, but this did not work, since in the authoring dialog there still was no checkbox/switch to make the field required (which was kinda expected).

this is the line in the markup which should be required if the author sets it to required in the authoring dialog:

`<input required="${required}" type="checkbox" name="campaignform-termsofservice"/>`

this is the whole html of the checkbox i want to be able to make required:

```
<div data-sly-test="${!empty}" class="form__text">
<label class="maut-checkbox--container">

    <input required="${required}" type="checkbox" name="campaignform-termsofservice"/>
    <span class="maut-checkbox--checkmark"></span>

    <span>${properties.checkboxtext @context='html'}</span>
    <div><a href="${properties.tncLink @ extension='html'}">${properties.tncText}</a></div>
    <div style="color:white;" class="authoring-error" data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit && !tncDate.tncLinkActivationDate}">${'b2x.maut.campaignform.dialog.tos.activationmessage' @ i18n, source='user'}</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="maut.field.tnc" value="${tncDate.tncLinkActivationDate}" />
</label>
</div>
```

Now i only need to figure out how i can show the option to set it to required in the authoring dialog.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your requirement. You have a checkbox in dialog which you need to make required or you have a checkbox in the component that should be always authored with some text? Also it will help if you can provide the whole markup of the component.

Comment: i have a checkbox in the component. an author should be able to make this checkbox required from the authoring dialog.

edited the question a bit, i hope this clarifies it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know how the `required=${required}` is implemented then first of all in html of the component look for something like `data-sly-use.required`. This will have a expression like `=com.project.yourProject.className` or some js file.

Lets discuss about the java case which is the most common way. What `data-sly-use` does is that it creates an object of the class that you gave in the expression. In your case your object is `required`. Then you need to check the java class that the expression evaluates to. Commonly all the backend logic code will be their and if some manipulations or validations are required to be done with the data that the author enters in the dialog will be their. This class will also contain annotations that maps the class variables with the property value of the dialog.
Hope this explains from where this `${required}` came from. It will be more clear to you if you look into the java class that is referred to by the `data-sly-use` expression.

Comment: thanks mate, with the info you gave me i was able to get it working as expected. thanks for your detailed information